# Synonym for「として」

Tags: words, adverbs, synonyms

I remember using a word that means "as (a role/identity)", roughly synonymous with 「として」. It was a word/phrase that I learned from writings that I had seen occasionally and adopted in my own language. But I can't seem to recall what it was. Examples: "as an American," "as a math teacher," "as a newcomer".

Comment: not sure it's what you are looking for, but what about ~的に?

Comment: ~の立場で or ～の役割で maybe? (or ～という立場/役割で(は)?) None of these are quite as versatile as として though.

Comment: Doesn't ring any bells (except として). Do you remember a typical context (sentence) where it's used?

Comment: @brokenlaptop Found it 「～たる～」でした...